# Sequelize include array of nested object - node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have relations:

(Track) -- M:1 --> (TrackChannel) <--1:M (Channel)
(User) -- M:1 --> (UserChannel) <--1:M (Channel)

- `Channel` model include object `Track` as `current_track_id` with relation one to one.
- `Track` and `Channel` is related many to many through `TrackChannel`
- `User` and `Channel` is related many to many through `UserChannel`

/* Channel.js:  */

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('channel', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    current_counter: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    track_counter: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    track_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'track',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.TIME,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: sequelize.fn('now')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.TIME,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: sequelize.fn('now')
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'channel',
    classMethods:{
      associate:function(models){
        this.belongsToMany(models.user, { onDelete: "CASCADE", foreignKey: 'user_id', otherKey: 'channel_id', through: 'userChannel' })
        this.belongsToMany(models.track, { onDelete: "CASCADE", foreignKey: 'track_id', otherKey: 'channel_id', through: 'trackChannel' })
        this.belongsTo(models.track, {foreignKey: 'current_track_id' , foreignKeyConstraint: true})
      }
    }
  });
};
```

### What you are doing?

That is my query for the channel. I use repository pattern:

```
return db.channel.findOne({
            raw:true,
            include: [
                { model: db.track, attributes: ['id', 'name','artist_name' ,'album_name'], where: {track_id, }, paranoid: true, required: false}
            ],
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        });
```

### What do you expect to happen?

I want to get:

```
{
  "id": "ce183d0a-e702-49a3-83b5-2912bbcf5283",
  "current_counter": 0,
  "track_counter": 0,
  "current_track_id": {} // object or null,
  "createdAt": "21:26:56.487217",
  "updatedAt": "21:26:56.487217",
  "tracks: [] // array or null
}
```

### What is actually happening?

I try to create query to get one channel where is included current track object and list of track. Now it looks like that:

```
{
  "id": "ce183d0a-e702-49a3-83b5-2912bbcf5283",
  "current_counter": 0,
  "track_counter": 0,
  "track_id": null,
  "createdAt": "21:26:56.487217",
  "updatedAt": "21:26:56.487217",
  "tracks.id": null,
  "tracks.name": null,
  "tracks.artist_name": null,
  "tracks.album_name": null,
  "tracks.trackChannel.id": null,
  "tracks.trackChannel.channel_id": null,
  "tracks.trackChannel.createdAt": null,
  "tracks.trackChannel.updatedAt": null,
  "tracks.trackChannel.track_id": null
}
```

Dialect: postgres 
Database version: 9.6
Sequelize version: 3.3.0

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4973 - that is solution to get `track` as array. But how to get related tracks

Comment: In case you get completely stuck with the `sequelize`, there is [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which perfectly supports the repository pattern, as shown in [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo), which can happily coexist with your sequelize code ;)

Comment: Thx I will take a look. But it does help me clean my code :)

Comment: You need to set `nest: true` https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4973#issuecomment-420178380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
findById: function(id) {
        return db.channel.findOne({
            logging: true,
            include: [
                { model: db.track, attributes: ['id', 'name','artist_name' ,'album_name'], as: 'track'},
                { model: db.track, attributes: ['id', 'name','artist_name' ,'album_name'], as: 'tracks', paranoid: true, required: false}
            ],
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 7):

Guess it'll help someone so giving another option.

You can use `nest:true` along with `raw:true` property given by sequelize.

result:

before:

```
{
        id: 1,
        createdBy: 1,
        'Section.id': 1,
        'Section.name': 'Breakfast',
}
```

After:

```
{
  id: 1,
  createdBy: 1,
  Section: {
      id: 1,
      name: ''
      }
}
```